# Load external SVG and containing JavaScript into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, xml, ajax, svg

I have an SVG document which contains JavaScript code. [As I asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900452/call-javascript-function-inside-svg-from-surrounding-html), I was trying to call a JavaScript function which was defined inside the SVG graphic from the loading HTML. I got an answer which linked to [this page](https://jwatt.org/svg/demos/scripting-across-embed.html) which explains how it works. However, it does not work in Google Chrome. Firefox does create all this correctly.

I was wondering if there is a one and only solution which appends the XML-Structure of the SVG file correctly to the DOM of the calling HTML and makes the Script callable. Is there a possibility using jQuery to simply load the file and append it on a div or something?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's an example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/html/get-embedded-svg-document-script.html) of how to call a function in a script contained in an svg that is referenced from html with each of `object`, `embed` and `iframe`.

Your question is a bit unclear, you should consider posting the example you have that didn't work.

Comment: 5.5 years after you supplied this answer the referenced svg document no longer contains any script functions.  Do recall what the trick was/is to calling a script contained in an svg?

Comment: You are right, @tobinjim - something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161388/calling-a-parent-window-function-from-an-iframe should work I think.