# Call SVG's external JavaScript function from the main html script?

Tags: javascript, svg

This is a similar question but I would like to know how to access the SVG's JavaScript functions when they are not embedded but are imported from an external file:

[Call svg javascript function inside html javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784237/call-svg-javascript-function-inside-html-javascript-function)

So, I'll attempt to make my question clear and hopefully not too convoluted.

I have main.html and main.js.

I also have someSVG.svg which imports someSVG.js which has a function, foo().

main.html imports someSVG.svg as an object element.

How do I call foo() from main.js?

Comment: create object for someSVG.js  so like this var some = new SomeSVG() and call some.foo()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you embed the SVG with an `<object>` tag, you can access the window object of the SVG with

```
var inner = document.querySelector('object').contentWindow
```

Just like the window object of the outer window, it provides all global variables that you would find in normal window, for example a script-defined `inner.foo()` or `inner.document`.

NOTE: Safari supports HTMLObjectElement.contentDocument from version 10, but not .documentWindow.

Comment: The SVG must also be same origin or CORS accessible.

Comment: @TheBlueCrayon wanted to comment, but couldn't because of missing reputation. He left an edit instead. Here's the full text: Safari doesn't support HTMLObjectElement.contentWindow for svg elements. Tested in Safari 11 and older for both Mac and iOS with this [simplified test case](https://plnkr.co/edit/lrf1qCcxY0NtU70GSI09?p=preview).

HTMLObjectElement.contentWindow isn't included in the [apple developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkitjs/htmlobjectelement?changes=latest_majo) at all.